# Community User offers Bounty?

Tags: support, bounty, user-accounts, community-user

I saw recently a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68740/10679) where the user `Community` has offered bounty to an answer. If `Community` is not a Human user, who decides the answers that will receive bounty from this user? Also, it is surprising that Community user has offered a bounty of 25 rep points. Shouldn't this be allowed for all users too?

(I recently awarded a bounty of 50 rep points *and*  I *wanted* (as opposed to *forced*) to give 50 rep points. But, this may come in handy for low rep users like me, perhaps, more so for those users with rep < 100.)

Comment: [The robot Community is very smart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2442/9467)! It knows the correct answer from the anonymous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties – When does a bounty expire?

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period
>   ending, half the bounty value will be automatically be awarded to the
>   top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a
>   score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no
>   reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the
>   bounty will be lost forever.

This means that someone added a bounty with a value of 50 to this question but didn't award it until the end of the bounty period. So half of the bounty has been automatically awarded to Paul Gaborit's answer by the [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) because it had received the most votes.

Comment: Thank you. I should have looked harder. :)